# Row_Number() alternative in Couchbase 6.0

Tags: oracle, couchbase, row-number, sql++

I have an oracle query which I want to translate into corresponding Couchbase's n1ql query.

```
select EMPNO, to_date,from_date, 
row_number() over (order by from_date asc) as JoiningRank,
row_number() over (order by from_date desc) as ExperinceRank
from [dbo].[EMPHISTORY]
```

As Row_Number() is being used here, I could not find an alternate way to write this query in n1ql.

I read somewhere that Row_Number() function (window functions) is available in 6.5 version.

1. Since I am using 6.0 right now, is there any way to implement
   this query in n1ql?
2. Does Couchbase 6.5 support this Row_Number()
   function? If yes, only EE or CE as well ?

Please help to re-write this query in n1ql.

Comment: you find an answer on the official  doc page: https://docs.couchbase.com/server/6.5/n1ql/n1ql-language-reference/windowfun.html#fn-window-row-number

Comment: @hotfix, I saw that offical doc but that is something which related to Couchbase 6.5. But I have to achieve it with Couchbase 6.0 not with 6.5

Comment: 6.5 CE (Community Edition) has not been released yet. row_number may or may not be in 6.5, but if it's something you really want to see, I'd recommend posting to https://forums.couchbase.com/c/n1ql and getting a discussion started, just in case.

Comment: Can you explain what you want to accomplish? Maybe we can find another way to do the same thing which is 6.0 compatible

Comment: https://forums.couchbase.com/t/row-number-alternative-in-couchbase-6-0/24656/2

Comment: @vsr, thanks for responding :)

Comment: @deniswsrosa, requiremnt is.. we have from_date column in oracle table as I mentioned in above query. Row_number is being used to get values (JoiningRank and ExperienceRank) in select clause (I forgot to write in select clause in above query). ----------------

(order by from_date asc) as JoiningRanK and (order by from_date desc) as ExperinceRank